# Duplicating Green Channel

Tags: rgb, photoshop, channel

I am a beginner in PS, and I am using PS 6.
While working on an image ,trying to splitting the image to the RGB components in the aim to work with only the Green component because i don't want to apply[image] the whole image ,So i say that i should duplicate only the channel indeed which is the green one ,but i can't find from where i cant get that.

Can anyone shows me some light please.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that looking quickly through the inter-webs you can follow this link for the information: http://www.dummies.com/software/adobe/photoshop/how-to-duplicate-and-delete-channels-in-photoshop-cs6/

Instructions from there say:

- Select your desired channel in the Channels panel.
- Select Duplicate Channel from the panel menu.
- The Duplicate Channel dialog box appears.
- In the Duplicate section, in the As field, name the channel.

You can also drag the channel to the New Channel icon at the bottom of the panel. If you do this, Photoshop provides a default name